# Setting a variable to the first value in array -

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm doing some beginners work on c#, working with visual studio.  I have to calculate the lowest number entered into an array by a user.  I need to write the code to do so manually.  Here's what I have that's relevant.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
                                                                                //Declare and initialise variables to be used in app.
    int[]   markArray = new int[10];                                            //Declare an array of integers to hold entered user values
    int     arrayPointer            = 0;                                        //Declare array pointer - This will be incremented after each function is carried out, so that the next user entered number will be placed in the next index position in the array.                                            
    int     lowestMark              = 0;                                        //Declare lowest mark

private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)                        //on a button click within the app
    {
        try                                                                     //Test value enter is number
        {
            markArray[arrayPointer] = Convert.ToInt32(textEntry.Text);          //Take value from text box and place in array cell if it is a int
        }
        catch                                                                   //Catch non ints
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must enter a number ");                        //if not int display error messsage  
        }

        int lowestMark = markArray[0];                                          // Set variable "lowestMark" to the value in the first position of the array.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (markArray[i] < lowestMark)                                      //  if there is an index with a value lower than the value assigned to "lowestMark"
            {
                lowestMark = markArray[i];                                      //Set this new lower value as the "lowestMark"
            }
        }
        arrayPointer++;                                                         //Increment array pointer
    }
```

So no matter which way i've fiddled with it, the value of `lowestMark` is always the same value I give it when I declare it.  If I `set it to 100` when I declare it, that's what will show up as the lowest mark when running.  So it would appear the line to set it to the value in index 0 in the array does nothing.  Even if fill every index in the array by entering 10 numbers, it will still read as 0.  I don't know why, which is weird because what I'm trying to do seems very simple.

`Enter a value into markArray`, at the `index` decided by `arrayPointer`, which `starts at 0.`  `Set lowestMark` to the same value in that same position.  Increment arrayPointer, so that the next value will be entered into index 1.

The program has a few other little functions it performs on that button click, but i've removed them to only keep the stuff that doesn't work

Comment: Instead of try/catch use int.TryParse().  Exceptions should not be used for flow control.

Comment: I will give you the best advice when facing this kind of problem: Press F5 and debug it step by step.

Comment: I would run it in the debugger and make sure the variable values are what you expect.  I'm confused by your use of `arrayPointer` and suspect that's the problem.

Comment: Since you know the previous value for lowestMark, and the new value entered by the user, you don't need to enumerate the array.

Comment: you increment the array pointer `arrayPointer++;` outside the loop also are you aware that array's in C# are `Zero Based` not `1` based.. use the debugger and you may be surprised to see how quickly you will see the error and or issue. read some free online .net tutorials understand what the term `Scope` means too http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson19

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are redeclaring your lowestMark as a local variable to the method.

```
int lowestMark = markArray[0];
```

If you want to use the instance variable don't redeclare it.

```
lowestMark = markArray[0];
```

Your instance variable, also called `lowestMark`, is being masked by the local variable so its value never changes.